# Running a complex loop query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have one problem in PostgreSQL.

This is my table (this table does not showing all data in image).

[image]

What is my requirement is:

**Step 1 :** find count of value (this is a column in table) Order by value **for today date**. So it will be like this and I did it.

[image]

**Step 2 :** find count of value for **last 30 days starting from today**. I am stuck here. Also one another thing is included in this step --

**Example** : today has 10 count for a value - kash, this will be 10x30, 
yesterday had 4 count for the same value , so will be 4x29, so the total sum would be

`(10x30) + (4x29) = 416.`

This calculation is calculated for each and every value.

This loop execute for **30 times (as I said before last 30 days starting from today)**. Take **today** as **thirtieth day**.

Query will just need to return two columns with **value and sum**, **ordered by the sum**.

Comment: Do you want a *running sum*? If so: `sum(...) OVER (...)` i.e. use sum as a window function.

Answer (score 1):

Add a WHERE clause to your existing query:

WHERE Timestamp > current_date - interval '30' day;

As far as ordering by the sum, add an ORDER BY clause.

ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC.

I do not believe that you will need a loop (CURSOR) for this query.

Comment: How can I manage this - "for example, today has 10 count for a value - kash, this will be 10x30, yesterday had 4 count for the same value , so will be 4x29, so the total sum would be

(10x30) + (4x29) = 416. Means how can do (10x30) + (4x29) calculation ?
"